# Creating an Onboarding Scene and facing difficulties with the UIHostingController

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, uihostingcontroller

I'm trying to create an onboarding screen using this (https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-create-a-onboarding-screen-in-swiftui-1/) tutorial. I have the below code in my SceneDelegate, but I'm getting the following error, "Cannot find 'UIHostingController' in scope." Anyone know how to remedy this?

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: OnboardingView())
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: It only works for ios13+

Comment: That worked! I just retyped everything.

Comment: `UIHostingController` is defined in `SwiftUI` - as its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller) clearly shows, so you need to `import SwiftUI` in order to be able to use it.